# 3D java array print, another way

Tags: java, arrays, printing, 3d

Hello fellow programmers!

I will post here the whole code i have. What I am trying to get is a full list of what's inside the array. I figured out how to do it with for loop and .length.

What I am asking here is: Is there any other way to print whole array?

Code starts here:

```
double[][][] skuskaTroj = new double[][][] {
        {
                { 12.44, 525.38, -6.28, 2448.32, 632.04 }, // [0][][]
                { -378.05, 48.14, 634.18, 762.48, 83.02 },
                { 64.92, -7.44, 86.74, -534.60, 386.73 } 
        },{
                { 48.02, 120.44, 38.62, 526.82, 1704.62 }, // [1][][]
                { 56.85, 105.48, 363.31, 172.62, 128.48 },
                { 906.68, 47.12, -166.07, 4444.26, 408.62 } 
        },{
                { 27, 263, 37.43, 26874, 5547 }, // [2][][]
                { 53, 978, 264, 338, 25287 },
                { 18765, 222, 363.28, 225.29, 12345 }, 
        }
};
for (int x = 0; x < skuskaTroj.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < skuskaTroj.length; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
            System.out.println("Hodnota je: " + skuskaTroj[x][y][z]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as you can see, in last for loop I used z < 5 because z < skuskaTroj.length didnt worked for me. It did not print the whole list. the 4th and 5th number in each line was skipped. Any idea why?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

real 3-dimensional arrays don't exist in Java. It's just an array of array of array.

```
for (int x = 0; x < skuskaTroj.length; x++){
  for (int y = 0; y < skuskaTroj[x].length; y++){
    for (int z =0; z < skuskaTroj[x][y].length; z++){
```

Of course you should also check for `null` if it's possible that any sub-arrays might be null.

Answer (score 1):

Because your array is 3 x 3 x 5 fields, `skuskaTroj.length` is 3 (the first part). If you want to refer to the actual array, the first loop end condition is `y < skuskaTroj[x].length` and the second `z < skuskaTroj[x][y].length`.